# How can I add three lines of y axis text while using expressions in two of the lines using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make a y axis that has three lines of text but also includes expressions.

`ggplot(weather)+ ylab(expression(paste('\nMean Temperature (degree C)\nTotal Solar Radiation (MJ m^-2)\nPrecipitation (cm)')))`

I have seen the work around using `atop()`, but, I can not figure out how to apply to three lines. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using unicode instead of `expression()`.

```
ggplot()+
ylab("Mean Temperature (\u00B0C)\nTotal Solar Radiation (MJ m\u207B\u00B2)\nPrecipitation (cm)")
```

I ran into a little bit of trouble when trying to display degree C without a space. Because `\U00B0C` gives a different symbol than `\U00B0`. Apparently by using a lowercase u it read the unicode then the letter `\u00B0C`